# How to combine data based on a unique identifier in mssql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Do you know how to combine data like below?

FROM:
id   account               phone     e-mail
1   ABC      (123) 456-7890
2   Def      (234) 567-8901      789@def.com
3   ABC                                    123@abc.com
4   Eco      (256) 789-3265      456@eco.com

TO:
id   account               phone     e-mail
1   ABC      (123) 456-7890      123@abc.com
2   Def      (234) 567-8901      789@def.com
3   Eco      (256) 789-3265      456@eco.com

Comment: Do you really want the ID for Eco to change from a 4 to a 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use aggregate functions, like:

```
SELECT Min(ID), Account, MAX(Phone), MAX(E-mail)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Account
```

This is assuming you don't want `id` to change like in your example, which would be a pretty terrible idea.

Comment: And as soon as you fix the bad data, put a unique index or constraint on the account field.